# Showing a function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show this function is analytic?

$f(z) = e^y \sin x + ie^y \cos x$  on $C$

Note: C is the domain.

Attempt

Partial derivatives of one equation are equal therefore cauchy reimann thm holds

Comment: Show that it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann Equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be verified by the [Cauchy Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). Let $u(x,y) = e^y\sin x$ and $v(x,y) = e^y\cos x$ so $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, then verify $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$and $$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$